# how to get value from derived class in c++

Tags: c++

I cannot access the value `name` from derived class `a` to the class `b`. How can I do that?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

class a
{

public:
    void getname()
    {
        string name; //trying to access value from other child class
        cout << "enter your name" << endl;
        getline(cin, name);
        cout << " your name is " << name << endl;
    }
};
class b: public a
{
    int age;

public:
    void old()
    {
        cout << "enter your age" << endl;
        cin >> age;
        cout << "your age is" << age << endl;
    }
    void print()
    {
        cout << " your name is " << name << endl; //cant access it
        cout << "your age is" << age << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    b o;
    o.getname();
    o.old();
    o.print();
    return 0;
}
```

I can only use the function in the class `b` but cannot access value from class `a`.

Comment: Please post the code as text in the question. It makes it easier for people to test it themselves.

Comment: thanks kinda new here

Comment: `name` is not an instance field. It's a **local variable** to your function, and there is no way to access it. If you had intended it to be an instance field, move its definition outside of the `getname` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared  **name** inside the getname() function, not as a class member.  Variables declared inside of functions have block scope, meaning they no-longer exist outside of that function.  Here is a bit more on scope. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope  It might also help you with class scope / class members.

Try changing class **a** like this:

```
class a {
   protected:
        string name;
    public:
        void getname() {
            cout << "enter your name" << endl;
            getline ( cin,name);
            cout << " your name is " << name << endl;
    }
};
```

Comment: already did it actually that is my first program but still show error

Comment: I just noticed that my answer had name as a private member, it should be protected. It's important that you don't also declare name in getname().

Comment: thank you sir I notice my error there  I really need to review the use of public protected and private